# how to detect application crashes?

Tags: .net, logic

if i am running a .net application and that application crashes frequently. i want to offer a crash recovery process such that after the crash, a message will be displayed to the user offering to  restart the application. how is it possible to write the code that does this inside the application and still run after it had crashed!
sounds like a weird loop of code but i'd like to know your experience on this.

Comment: I would also suggest that you offer to submit details of the crash as well so you can fix those bugs. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event and do the stuff from the event handler.

Comment: but if the application crashed, would this event still be fired? im not finding it logic that code within the application would still run after a crash

Comment: After crash it will be fired. And eve would allow to send bug-report to email or report-service.

Comment: @Ali Tarhini: as msdn says [Starting with the .NET Framework version 4, this event is not raised for exceptions that corrupt the state of the process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx). AppDomain will be unloaded anyway. The purpose of this event is to run some recovery logic.

Comment: @Ali Tarhini: depends how you define "crash". at this point the application is still semi-alive, and I have had good success with writing logging information to log4net from this event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Write the code in the Main method. (Assuming it is Windows Application or Console Application it will have one).

Basically your main method ends up looking something like this:

```
public static Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        RunApplication(args);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        RunCrashRecovery(args, ex);
    }
}
```

Where `RunApplication` is what you would have put in `Main` originally and `RunCrashRecovery` is the code that sends out the crash information and asks the user if they want to restart.

Answer (score -1):

What do mean with crash? If you get an exception you could use try and catch to handle these errors.
If there is no exception you should try to change the code so that the program does not crash.
EDIT: Last is possible if you e.g. use the same variables in multiple threads.